# understanding kafka, consumer groups, and topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to understand kafka's consumer groups notion.

All the documentation makes it look as if a consumer group is used to parallelize reads within a particular topic. But I've also read that consumers can subscribe to multiple topics.

So my question is -- what is the relationship between consumer groups and topics? can 2 different consumers that belong to the same consumer group read from different topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All the documentation makes it look as if a consumer group is used to
>   parallelize reads within a particular topic. But I've also read that
>   consumers can subscribe to multiple topics.

Yes and yes.

Kafka sends every published message to every consumer group, but only one consumer in each group. If you want queue like behavior where every message is received/processed by exactly one consumer, then use one consumer group per topic. If you want pub/sub behavior where every consumer gets one copy of every message, then every consumer should use a distinct consumer group.

> So my question is -- what is the relationship between consumer groups
>   and topics? can 2 different consumers that belong to the same consumer
>   group read from different topics?

It's best to think: do you want queue behavior (1 msg -> 1 and only one consumer)? Or pub-sub behavior (1 msg -> every consumer)? Or some hybrid of the two? Once you have chosen that, lay out consumer groups accordingly.

To directly answer the question: You generally can organize any way that you want. The most logical way to think of it is each topic has N consumer groups. You can use the same consumer group string on different topics, but I don't think that holds any significance.

Comment: Also, if a consumer is consuming from multiple topics, most would logically view or label them as separate consumers. They might be running in the same process space, but from a Kafka perspective, they are generally separate consumers. The exception here is when a Kafka consumer is joining or merging messages from multiple input topics. then you would logically consider that one consumer.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is -- what is the relationship between consumer groups and topics?

A simple example:

Imagine you have a `publisher` who pushes messages to the `topic` called ***ORDER_CREATION***. You have a distributed system with 4 server instances, which means you have 4x `consumers` listening to this `topic`.

***Problem***: Of course you don't want all `4 x consumers` to consume the message and create the order. This way you have to handle the concurrent transactions by yourself. You only want exactly `1x consumer` to consume the topic and create the order. This is possible with `groups`.

You put your 4x consumers into a `group` and the `message queue` makes sure only ***1 consumer*** of this group consumes the message.